# Please explain this from the Subversion FAQ? "Don't use a file, use a template"

Tags: svn, version-control

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit

> **I have a file in my project that every developer must change, but I don't want those local mods to ever be committed. How can I make 'svn commit' ignore the file?**
>
> The answer is: don't put that file under version control. Instead, put a template of the file under version control, something like "file.tmpl".
>
> Then, after the initial 'svn checkout', have your users (or your build system) do a normal OS copy of the template to the proper filename, and have users customize the copy. The file is unversioned, so it will never be committed. And if you wish, you can add the file to its parent directory's svn:ignore property, so it doesn't show up as '?' in the 'svn status' command.
>
> http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit

The only use of .tmpl files I've come across in learning about Subversion are the hook files, where they give you a template say post-commit.tmpl which has an example shell script in it, and you're supposed to rename it without the .tmpl and put it in the `hooks` folder.

I'm afraid I don't get what this FAQ answer means. Are files with .tmpl extensions somehow ignored by Subversion? Do I have to rename the file?

Say my system has `database-config.php` in a file on the server, and I want to develop on my local machine with a different `database-config.php` reflecting local conditions. Do I have to call it `database-config.php.tmpl`?

Can someone talk me step-by-step through how I would follow the instructions in the answer?

By the way, I'm aware there are other similar questions, but I don't believe any of them addresses this specific FAQ question, or asks for it to be spelled out.

Comment: You are expecting subversion to do something... When they actually say: we don't support this, at most you can store a template file in svn (with the most common setting prefilled, in the desired format, etc.) and just tell (you, personally, not 'the server') to copy that and put in their own configuration. The calling it _'anything.tmpl'_ is just a suggestion, you might as well call it _'oogabooga'_ if you like.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the step-by-step instructions would be: 1) when you set up your repository, delete database-config.php or don't add it in the first place. 2) Create and add a file called something called database-config-[EDIT-ME].php with example code. 3) Developers edit that file and save it as database-config.php in their own Working Copy. 4) Now the example file is in the repository, but not the real file. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AmbroseChapel - yes, except p.3 - there aren't (almost) any reason to have **real config** in WC - when you prepare code for testing with any used build-system, convert template to usable file in final destination (while you can have data-file in repo and don't forget svn:ignore it)

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: yep seems about it.

Comment: Add an answer of some kind and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I think your point about 3) by the way is more about compiled software, not websites. It may be necessary to have config data in a file in a website. Though now I think about it, a much better way to fix my problem is to move the config file completely out of the web-accessible area to a place which isn't under version control.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Wrikken - Add the most standard file with common preferred settings and "Store" it in the repository. Now when the user checks it out -  before anything elese - He must first:

1. Edit it (eg. ooga_Template.cpp) according to his local environment
2. Save it as a copy - with the original(expected) file name (eg. ooga.cpp)
3. and NOT version this(ooga.cpp) file (i.e. not attach it to the SVN).

You can name the template file anything - but yes naming it different from the Original file name - is highly recommended. This way that file can harmlessly sit along the local version of that file, and it will make it compulsory for the user to modify the file before he can use it.